# Java Compiling Pattern in between two Strings (Dynamic)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to combine all the characters in between the expression: "participantIdentities" & a variable that I have set as summonerID. I'm extracting all this information from a string called matchinfo, and the string goes like this:

`"participantIdentities":[{"participantId":1,"player":{"summonerId":36889900,"summonerName":"intalan","matchHistoryUri":"/v1/stats/player_history/NA1/51395230","profileIcon":744}},{"participantId":2,"player":{"summonerId":32741714,`

And it keeps going on. Because the summonerID changes, I have to set it as a variable. Right now, it's set to 32741714.

This is what I have so far:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(
    "\"participantIdentities\": (.*?)"+summonerID+"", Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(matchinfo); 

if (matcher2.find() == true) {
    participantIDinformation = matcher2.group(1).toString();
    System.out.println(participantIDinformation);
}
```

I would expect it to return all the information in between the participantID and the summonerID but it's not working.

Comment: What is it returning?

Comment: The matcher2.find() is returning false, so it's failing to recognize the pattern at all.

Comment: Use JSON parser for this please. There are tons of good JSON parser out there for you to choose. Don't parse it with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space after `\"participantIdentities\":` in your regex but you do not in your data.

Comment: Indeed, Java regex patterns does not ignore spaces and treat them as space in the pattern.